# java -postgresql last inserted id on insertion not getting

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a function for insertion in `postgresql` as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_orderhead(order_id integer, order_dt text, customer_id integer, route_id integer, routenum integer, ordertype text, create_station_id integer, create_stationtype text, create_time text, create_user_id integer, tran_time text, tran_user_id integer) RETURNS integer AS $BODY$
INSERT INTO ordermaster
VALUES(DEFAULT,
       order_dt,
       customer_id,
       route_id,
       routenum,
       ordertype,
       create_station_id,
       create_stationtype,
       create_time,
       create_user_id,
       tran_time,
       tran_user_id) returning order_id $BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL VOLATILE COST 100;


ALTER FUNCTION insert_orderhead(integer, text, integer, integer, integer, text, integer, text, text, integer, text, integer) OWNER TO postgres;
```

And I am using java to insert and I am calling as follows:

```
cstorderhead = conn.prepareCall("{call insert_orderhead(?,?)}");
                    cstorderhead.setString(1, order_date);
                    cstorderhead.setInt(2, custidup);
                       .........
                    cstorderhead.executeUpdate();
```

The value is getting inserted correctly.

I need to **return the last inserted id** here it is the serial auto increment.

I tried as follows:

```
ResultSet rstd = cstorderhead.getGeneratedKeys();
                    if (rstd.next()) {
                        int newId = rstd.getInt(1);
                            out.print("Value returned=="+newId);
                    }
```

But it is not returning the last inserted id. What change I need to make my code to get it?

This is the table definition:

```
create table ordermaster 
(
  order_id serial NOT NULL, order_dt text, customer_id integer, route_id integer, routenum integer, ordertype text, create_station_id integer, create_stationtype text, create_time text, create_user_id integer, tran_time text, tran_user_id integer, CONSTRAINT order_id PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);
```

Comment: If you want to get a generated key from a stored procedure (or function), then you will need to return it yourself from your function. The JDBC generated keys facility (which BTW needs to be explicitly enabled for a statement) only works for normal DML, and is **not specified** for callable statements.

Comment: Unrelated but: why are you passing a `date` as a `String`. Dates should never be passed nor _stored_ as string values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name my date is in string format yyyymmdd in string format so it is not a problem

Comment: Passing dates as strings **is** a problem. What prevents you of storing `20150231`?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name it is irrelevent in this context buddy. Please help me with my current issue :(

Comment: I said it was unrelated, but it is **still**  a very bad idea to store a date in a `varchar` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `getGeneratedKeys()` with a `CallableStatement`. However as your `insert` is "hidden" in the function, you also can't use a regular `PreparedStatement` with `getGeneratedKeys()` because the driver will append a `RETURNING` clause to the SQL statement - which doesn't work with a function call.

I see two solutions to your problem:

### 1. Change the function to return the value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_orderhead(
    p_order_id integer, 
    p_order_dt text, 
    p_customer_id integer, 
    p_route_id integer, 
    p_routenum integer, 
    p_ordertype text, 
    p_create_station_id integer, 
    p_create_stationtype text, 
    p_create_time text, 
    p_create_user_id integer, 
    p_tran_time text, 
    p_tran_user_id integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
   INSERT INTO ordermaster 
     (order_dt, customer_id, route_id, routenum, ordertype, create_station_id, create_stationtype, create_time,create_user_id,tran_time, tran_user_id)
   values 
     (p_order_dt, p_customer_id, p_route_id, p_routenum, p_ordertype, p_create_station_id, p_create_stationtype, p_create_time, p_create_user_id, p_tran_time, p_tran_user_id) 
   returning  orderline_id;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Note that I removed the unused `order_id` parameter and renamed the other two parameters - because it is usually not a good idea to have parameters with the same name as columns.

Then in your code you can use the function like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select insert_order(?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1, "foo");
pstmt.setInt(2, 42);

rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

if (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println("Generated ID is: " + rs.getInt(1));
}
```

### 2. Query the sequence manually:

After calling your function, you can run another statement to obtain the last generated sequence value:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select lastval()");
if (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println("Generated ID is: " + rs.getInt(1));
}
```

The above will only work if the function doesn't insert into multiple tables. If it does, you need to use `currval()` with the sequence name:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select currval('ordermaster.order_id_seq')");
if (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println("Generated ID is: " + rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Comment: Getting error ` You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 8Error occurred while adding order details`

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name updated. please check it budddy!!

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name updated the stored procedure as per your suggestion, please check it buddy. help me out :(

Comment: @Santhucool: I don't see a `create table` statement in your question. But the error message sounds as if you are not using the correct data types for either the parameters or the `setXXX()` call.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name  please check above!!

Comment: @Santhucool: your columns in the `insert` statement don't line up with the columns in the table. If you qualify them properly in the `insert` statement you can see that you apparently are not providing a value for the `order_id` and thus the value of `order_dt` is put into the `order_id` column - that's where the casting error occurs. See my edit - I also changed the parameter names to avoid name clashes. You need to decide what to do with the `order_id` column though. And apparently the `returning` clause must return the `orderline_id` column.

Comment: order_id is the type serial in postgresql that need not to be provided manually thats why I am putting it as default. That you can note in my code!! I have tried your function with 'orderline_id' but it is not working getting error

Comment: No, order_id is **not** a serial it's defined as `integer` (unless you have pasted the wrong table definition). The serial column is `orderline_id`

Comment: orderline_id  is not a column of table at all then from where it comes form?

Comment: You posted that: `CREATE TABLE ordermaster ( orderline_id serial NOT NULL, `

Comment: Sorry buddy `order_id serial NOT NULL,
  order_dt text,
  customer_id integer,
  route_id integer,
  routenum integer,
  ordertype text,
  create_station_id integer,
  create_stationtype text,
  create_time text,
  create_user_id integer,
  tran_time text,
  tran_user_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT order_id PRIMARY KEY (order_id)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92734/discussion-between-santhucool-and-a-horse-with-no-name).