# Error with returning value using Java to perform Upsert in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I have seen several post about this topic ([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691715/get-returning-value-from-postgresql-via-java),[post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212417/java-postgresql-last-inserted-id-on-insertion-not-getting),[post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241003/how-to-get-a-value-from-the-last-inserted-row)). In all of them the solution looks very easy, but I'm not able to get the value of the returning value.

This is what I have tried so far:

**Option 1:**

```
int affectedRows =pstmt.executeUpdate();    
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet(); 
    if (rs.next())
        updated = rs.getBoolean(1);
```

Result:
`java.lang.NullPointerException` cause by if `(rs.next())`

**Option 2:**

```
ResultSet rs =pstmt.executeQuery(); 
    if (rs.next())
        {updated = rs.getBoolean(1);}
```

Result:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query`

**Option 3:**

```
boolean hasResult =pstmt.execute(); 
logger.info("hasResult: " + hasResult);
//if (hasResult) {
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet(); 
    if (rs.next())
        updated = rs.getBoolean(1);             
//}
logger.info("updated: " + updated);
```

Result:
`java.lang.NullPointerException` cause by if `(rs.next())` also notice the `hasResult: false`

The query created into the Java code looks like the following:

```
INSERT INTO public."tablename"( "field1", "field2", ...,"field n")
VALUES('value1','value2',...,'value n') 
ON CONFLICT ("UniqueID") 
DO UPDATE SET "field1" = 'value3' ,..., "Updated"=true 
RETURNING "Updated"
```

If I execute the query using, for example, pgadmin, I see the RETURNING "Updated" value

[image: pgadmin]

Note: In each option the query is executed without problem, but I can not get the "Updated" value

This are the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15</version>
</dependency>
```

And the connection string:

```
jdbc:postgresql://google/postgres?cloudSqlInstance=<...>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<...>&password=<...>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Option 3) works for me. Which driver version are you using?

Comment: Hi, @a_horse_with_no_name I have added the dependency I'm currently using to the main post

Comment: That's not the (native) Postgres driver, so maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

When I created the `PreparedStatement pstmt` object I used `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

The use of `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` constant is to used with getGeneratedKeys to get the auto-generated keys of all rows created by that execution.

Like I want an specific returned element I should use:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql)`.
Cannot see where sql is passed.

 or
`PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);`

`ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();`